# Configure date format for Telerik fields

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, telerik

I have an existing application (C Sharp, .NET, Telerik reports) which was not planned for international support, and a new international customer.  The many date fields on the reports are formatted with "{0:MM/dd/yy}" in the "Format" field of each date field's properties.  Our new customer wants dd/MM/yy.

I want to make this a culture setting, but will need to be able to control it somewhat; many of the fields are not big enough to support 4-digit years, for instance, and the normal short date (in the US) is MM/dd/yyyy.

I am fairly certain I have seen an article explaining how to alter a culture definition (in an RESX file?) so that "{0:d}" would use a "short date format" that the programmer specified; then the date fields could use "default culture" (so that they change according to culture) and a "Format" setting of "{0:d}", and Telerik would get the custom version of "short date format" so I could set it to MM/dd/yy for one culture and dd/MM/yy in another.

But I can't find the article now.  Can anyone explain how to do this, or point me to that or another useful article?  10 pages of google search have revealed lots of things about javascript, code-behind, what a culture is, and how to format dates, but not how to alter a culture definition so that "short date" means what I want it to mean in each culture.